# put a code at the right side of the last line of paragraph using css

Tags: html, css

How can I write a code at the end of each paragraph and align it to the right (in the same line as the last line of the paragraph.)?
**Update:** Using `float:right` is what I intended to do but there is a problem in vertically aligning the code with the last line of the paragraph especially when there is a large difference between font size. You can see the result of the following code:
(I put two codes at the end of the paragraph, one with the alignright class and the other without it to make the problem more clear in the result.)
[image]

I want the result to be like this:
[image]

```css
body {font-size: 25px;}
      code {
        background-color: lightgray;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      .alignright {float: right;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum.
      <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
      <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.
      <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
      <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... what do you want to happen? Is this different to your expected output - can you show a screenshot of what you want vs what you have?

Answer (score 1):

```css
    body {font-size: 25px;}
          code {
            background-color: lightgray;
            font-size: 15px;
          }
     p{position: relative;
    width: 100%;}
    .alignright {float: right;position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 8px;
}}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>
          Lorem, ipsum.
          <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
          <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
          <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

---

- `position` set position on `p` and `.alignright`
- `right` set 0 and `top` set 8px

Answer (score 0):

```css
.alignright {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta deleniti
      debitis obcaecati totam eaque ex laborum exercitationem eveniet, nisi
      voluptatibus quibusdam, placeat perferendis dolores illum doloribus sequi
      dignissimos nam molestiae.
      <code class="alignright">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</code>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tested `float:right` before, but there was a problem that I updated and mentioned in the post so I supposed that this is not the correct way to do this. Please let me know if you have a solution for the vertical aligning.

Comment: yes, we can see you updated the question but can you post a picture of what result you really want?

Comment: Updated again. I just want a vertically aligned code at the end of the paragraph with the last line of it but when I make the code float it seems to align with the top of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I've just gave it width of 100% and display to block

```css
.alignright {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta deleniti
      debitis obcaecati totam eaque ex laborum exercitationem eveniet, nisi
      voluptatibus quibusdam, placeat perferendis dolores illum doloribus sequi
      dignissimos nam molestiae.
      <code class="alignright">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</code>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you but I wanted the code to be in the same line as the last line of paragraph. sorry if the post wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      .alignright {
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        justify-content:right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta deleniti
      debitis obcaecati totam eaque ex laborum exercitationem eveniet, nisi
      voluptatibus quibusdam, placeat perferendis dolores illum doloribus sequi
      dignissimos nam molestiae.
      <code class="alignright">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</code>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated the post to be more clear. I want the code to be in the same line with the last line of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to apply a positioning context to `p` via:

- `position: relative`

and then, instead of `float: right`, apply the following styles to `.alignright`:

- `position: absolute;`
- `bottom: 0;`
- `right: 0;`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}

code {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.alignright {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem, ipsum.
  <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
  <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.
  <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
  <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {font-size: 25px;}
      code {
        background-color: lightgray;
        font-size: 15px;
      }
      .alignright {float: right; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Lorem, ipsum.
      <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
      <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecteturdfdsfdsfdfd sdvdc dvd  dv adipisicing.
      <code>Lorem, ipsum.</code>
      <code class="alignright">Lorem, ipsum.</code>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

- `set margin-top: 8px;` on `.alignright` class